# ssis send email task

Tags: sql, ssis

I am working on a SSIS Package in which I need to send an email to all those users whose email id will be retrieved after executing a Stored Procedure in the email id column

```
624191  Accepted    Test        abc@xyz.co.uk
624870  Accepted    Rejected    lmn@xyz.co.uk
624870  Cancelled   Pending     pqr@xyz.co.uk
```

Basically I need to send an email to all 3 email ids.

Steps followed:

1. created `SQL Execute task` to execute the SP and created a output variable.
2. created a `foreach` loop container and calling that variable from foreach through ADO enumerator.
3. if I put the send email task in to the `foreach` loop container then I need to put a emailid in the TO section but I don't know how to call those email id from stored procedure directly.
4. I dont know what to put in a Script task.

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL Server is configured to do so, you could use  `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`

[More info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

Comment: is there any way to do it via SSIS? how to put those 3 email ids into the variable and calling that variabe in the TOLine Section of Send Mail Task?

Comment: If you place your address in a semicolon delimited list in a user variable you can assign that variable to an Expression Property. So right click Properties, Expressions, click the "..." to add a new expression, select the Property "ToLine" and put your variable in the Expression box....

Comment: I have never done it before. Can you please tell me as how to do it i.e. how to create a semicolon delimited list in a user variable? I have just created a user variable with all email id (without delimited) and calling that variable in ToLine but it's not working because I am not doing it right.

Comment: Why don't you just modify your stored procedure to return the all of the emails as a single semicolon delimited VARCHAR (or create a secondary SP to do so). That might be easiest path...